# Can PGF plot the integral of any specified function?

Tags: pgfplots

How can I use the `pgf` maths engine to plot the integral of any function?

For example `\addplot {int(cos(x))}` does not work.

Comment: Wow, TeX doing integrals...  *That* is ambitious.  Though, if you mean *numerical*, not *symbolic* (as your question seems to suggest), it is probably pretty doable.  (Theoretically, symbolic is of course doable as well - but not worth the effort imho.)

Comment: I don't think the _pgf_ math engine was designed for this. You could use an external program to carry out computations like this.

Comment: Or luatex, though it might be reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Numerical integration (e.g. trapezoid or Simpson's rule) can be done easily enough with a for loop starting by `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`. Symbolic integration, though, is a different problem altogether.

Comment: I decided the simplest would be to calculate the symbolic integration on [wolframalpha.com](http://wolframalpha.com) Thanks all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As was said in the comments, you PGF can't compute the antiderivative analytically. If the function is reasonably linear, you can quite easily compute the antiderivative numerically, similar to the approach in  [Get derivative of a function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73920/get-derivative-of-a-function/73924#73924).

Here's an approach using PGFPlotstable to calculate the function values:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstablenew[
    create on use/x/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow/50}
    },
    create on use/y/.style={
        create col/expr={cos(deg(\thisrow{x}))}
    },
    create on use/int/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma+(\thisrow{y}+\prevrow{y})/2*(\thisrow{x}-\prevrow{x})}
    },
    columns={x,y,int}
]
{200}
\datatableA

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[no markers, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)}, anchor=north}, legend entries={Original function, Analytical antiderivative, Numerical antiderivative}]
\addplot [gray] table {\datatableA};
\addplot [line width=3pt, red!50, domain=0:4] {sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [black] table [y=int] {\datatableA};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\[3ex]

\pgfplotstablenew[
    create on use/x/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow/50-2}
    },
    create on use/y/.style={
        create col/expr={\thisrow{x}^3}
    },
    create on use/int/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma+(\thisrow{y}+\prevrow{y})/2*(\thisrow{x}-\prevrow{x})}
    },
    columns={x,y,int}
]
{200}
\datatableB


\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[no markers, samples=500]
\addplot [gray] table {\datatableB};
\addplot [line width=3pt, red!50, domain=-2:2] {1/4*x^4};
\addplot [black] table [y expr=\thisrow{int}-4] {\datatableB};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. Would it be possible to hide it all inside a style, say `\addplot[int] {cos(deg(x))};` (that is automatic definition of the function to be used in the table and `\addplot table` behind the scene)?

Comment: @cjorssen: That should be possible, but it would take a bit of work...

Comment: Then I guess I should start a bounty to reward that bit of work `:)`

Comment: @cjorssen: That seems like an abuse of the plot *style*.  IMO the style of a plot shouldn't change the function.  But you could hack into `pgfmath` so that it could parse something like `int(cos(deg(x)),x,0,1)`.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Here is a feature request for this: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/99/

Answer (score 12):

PSTricks can do it. Here is an example for the default Simpson method (Integral of sin(x)+cos(x):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}

 \begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1pt](-1,-1.5)(7,2.5)
 \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-1.2)(6.75,2.5)
 \psplot[linecolor=red,algebraic]{0}{6.5}{cos(x)+sin(x)}
 \psCumIntegral[plotpoints=500,Simpson=10,
   linecolor=blue]{0}{6.5}{ RadtoDeg dup cos exch sin add }
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Run it with `xelatex`. `pst-func` also knows `\psIntegral`, see documentation.

[image]

Comment: Could you make an answer for [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129741/19356) as well? I have no idea because of 2 variables.