# How to plot a function in integral form with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

how to plot the function `$f:x\mapsto
\int_x^{2x}\frac{4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\, \textrm{d}t$` with `TikZ`?

[image]

Comment: you could try using `pgfplots`. would be nice though, if you could provide a MWE of what you've already got.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't think is possible to use durectly `TikZ` or `pgfplots` to plot such a function. I suggest to use another program (like `Matlab` or `Mathematica`) to generate a data file for this function and then to plot the file using `pgfplots`.

Comment: [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) would be a useful tool if you follow Red's suggestion.

Comment: Integration is exclusive to  PSTricks and Asymptote (leave Metapost aside). People have been doing amazing stuff with them. example, http://pstricks.blogspot.de/2012/06/lattracteur-de-lorenz-avec-pstricks.html You can make a table of small increments though with pgfplots

Comment: As for compilation times, it would be far faster to `\includegraphics` a generated pdf (made with Mathematica/etc.) and then superimpose ticks and labels. Doing things like this with TeX-based tools, while certainly possible, isn't practical in the end.

Comment: If you want to use `TikZ` then, you could use `gnuplot`. It doesn't support integration natively, but you can find examples easily googling them. Another alternative would be using `LuaTeX` and doing the integration in Lua.

Answer (score 38):

[image]

MWE using adaptive Simpson integration (`Asymptote`):

```
% s.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
size(300,200,IgnoreAspect);
import graph;
real F(real t){return 4/sqrt(1+t^4);}
real f(real x){return simpson(F,x,2x);}
pen axPen=darkblue;
pen fPen=red+1bp;
draw(graph(f,-7,7,n=200),fPen);
string noZero(real x) {return (x==0)?"":string(x);}
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
xaxis(axPen,LeftTicks(noZero,Step=2));
yaxis(axPen,RightTicks(noZero,Step=0.5));

label("$f:x\mapsto \displaystyle\int_x^{2x}"
     +"\frac{4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\, \textrm{d}t$"
  ,(1.7,f(1.7)),NE);
\end{asy}
\end{document}    

% To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:
% 
%     sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
%     add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
% 
% and run `latexmk -pdf s.tex`.
```

Comment: That's great, I've to investigate Asymptote someday.

Comment: @PSTikZ: see `Asymptote` answer added.

Comment: I attempted to compile your code as discussed [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11066574#11066574) but I did not get the asymptote output. The only output I got is the graphics caption.

Comment: @PSTikZ: the answer is pretty simple: `latexmk` script expects
`latexmkrc`, not the `latexmkrc.pl`. Something like `\immediate\write18{mv latexmkrc.pl latexmkrc}` `\immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf integral.tex}` works (just checked).

Comment: `mv` is not recognized....

Comment: What is the correct extension for `latexmkrc` file? If I ignore the extension, `filecontents` will use `.tex` by default.

Comment: @PSTikZ: The correct extension for `latexmkrc` is empty.
It seems that `TeX` has problems with creation files
with empty extension, at least on some file systems.
On `windows` file systems `latexmkrc.` might work.

Answer (score 26):

Here is the PSTricks answer. I slightly changed the `\psCumIntegral` macro from `pst-func` to account for the different integration limits:

```
\documentclass[preview, varwidth, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\makeatletter
\def\psMyIntegral{\pst@object{psMyIntegral}}
\def\psMyIntegral@i#1#2#3{%
  \begin@OpenObj%
  \addto@pscode{
    /xStart #1  def
    /dx #2 #1 sub \psk@plotpoints\space div def
    /a #1 def
    /b a 2 mul def
    /scx { \pst@number\psxunit mul } def
    /scy { \pst@number\psyunit mul } def
    tx@FuncDict begin /SFunc { #3 } def end
    \psk@plotpoints 1 add {
      a b \psk@Simpson
      tx@FuncDict begin Simpson I end
      scy a scx exch a xStart eq {moveto}{lineto}ifelse
      /a a dx add def
      /b a 2 mul def
    } repeat
  }%
  \end@OpenObj%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.8,yunit=1.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-2)(7,2)
  \psMyIntegral[plotpoints=500, linecolor=red]{-7}{7}{4 exp 1 add sqrt 4 exch div}
  \psaxes[Dy=0.5, arrows=->](0,0)(-7,-2)(7,2)
  \rput[rt](7,2){$f:x\mapsto \displaystyle\int_x^{2x} \frac{4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\, \textrm{d}t$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

EDIT: Here comes a more general macro `\psVarIntegral`, which allows to specify both limits `a(x)` and `b(x)` in terms of functions operating on the `x`-value on the stack.

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\makeatletter
\def\psVarIntegral{\pst@object{psVarIntegral}}
\def\psVarIntegral@i#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \begin@OpenObj%
  \addto@pscode{
    /xStart #1 def
    /xCurr #1 def
    /dx #2 #1 sub \psk@plotpoints\space div def
    /a #1 #3 def
    /b #1 #4 def
    /scx { \pst@number\psxunit mul } def
    /scy { \pst@number\psyunit mul } def
    tx@FuncDict begin /SFunc { #5 } def end
    \psk@plotpoints 1 add {
      a b \psk@Simpson
      tx@FuncDict begin Simpson I end
      scy xCurr scx exch xCurr xStart eq {moveto}{lineto}ifelse
      /xCurr xCurr dx add def
      /a xCurr #3 def
      /b xCurr #4 def
    } repeat
  }%
  \end@OpenObj%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.8,yunit=1.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-2)(7,2)
  \psVarIntegral[plotpoints=500, linecolor=red]{-7}{7}{}{2 mul}{4 exp 1 add sqrt 4 exch div}
  \psaxes[Dy=0.5, arrows=->](0,0)(-7,-2)(7,2)
  \rput[rt](7,2){$f:x\mapsto \displaystyle\int_x^{2x} \frac{4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\, \textrm{d}t$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: aargh too slow...... +1. You can actually get the functions in the limit as arguments though.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the hint. I added the more general `\psVarIntegral`, which takes two additional functions to calculate the limits.

Comment: I have no idea how to read `4 exp 1 add sqrt 4 exch div` as `\frac{4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}`. Could you help me?

Comment: @Sigur That is [reverse polish notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Explanation) and assumes, that the `t` value is already on the stack.

Comment: @Christoph, now I understand. Specially because the part *already on the stack*. Thanks.

Comment: @Christoph, could you help me to write `\exp(\frac{-1}{t(\alpha-t)})` in that notation?

Comment: @Sigur  (with some `alpha` defined first) : `/alpha 3.1415 def Euler -1 t alpha t sub mul div exp`

Answer (score 15):

Here is another, quite compact, **PSTricks** solution.

The **TikZ** solution using the same numerical approach is given below to satisfy the OP.

`\pstODEsolve` (`RKF45` method) from the `pst-ode` package is used to solve the definite integral between *x* and 2 *x* at each of the 501 plot points in the interval [-7,7]. The initial value for each `\pstODEsolve` invocation is set to zero to immediately get the definite integral at 2 *x*.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-ode,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{/result {} def} %initialise empty result list
\multido{\nX=-7.00+0.028}{501}{% 501 plotpoints
  %integral = [x 0 2x F(2x)] (two output points)-------------v   v----initial value
  \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{integral}{t | y[0]}{\nX}{2*\nX}{2}{0.0}{4/sqrt(1+t^4)}
  %append [x F(2x)] to results list
  \pstVerb{/result [result integral exch pop exch pop] cvx def}
}
%plot result
\psset{xunit=0.8,yunit=1.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-2)(7,2)
  \psaxes[Dy=0.5, arrows=->](0,0)(-7,-2)(7,2)
  \listplot[linecolor=red]{result}
  \rput[rt](7,2){$f:x\mapsto \displaystyle\int_x^{2x} \frac{4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\, \textrm{d}t$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

TikZ/PGFPlots solution, requires `pdflatex --shell-escape`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{xyz.tex}
  \input pst-ode \input multido
  \pstVerb{/statefile (result.dat) (w) file def}
  \multido{\nX=-7.00+0.028}{501}{% 501 plotpoints
    \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{integral}{t | y[0]}{\nX}{2*\nX}{2}{0}{4/sqrt(1+t^4)}
    \pstVerb{[integral exch pop exch pop] tx@odeDict begin writeresult end}
  }
  \pstVerb{statefile closefile} \bye
\end{filecontents}
\immediate\write18{tex xyz}\immediate\write18{dvips xyz}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf -dNOSAFER xyz.ps}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=center, axis y line=center, unit vector ratio=0.8 1.5,
      ymin=-2, ymax=2, xtick={-7,...,6}, ytick={-2,-1.5,...,1.5},
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1},
    ]
    \addplot[red] table {result.dat};
    \node [anchor=north east] at (axis cs:7,2)
      {$f:x\mapsto \displaystyle\int_x^{2x} \frac{4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\, \textrm{d}t$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\immediate\write18{tex xyz && dvips xyz && ps2pdf -dNOSAFER xyz.ps}` does work as well and simpler.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch Yes I know. But it is Bash syntax and hence not portable, say, to a Windows box. Therefore I used two separate `\write18`'s.

Comment: Nice! I'm trying to adapt the code to the function `\int_{-\infty}^{x}exp(-1/(t*(2-t)))dt` but after `latex` and `dvips` the `ps` file loads forever and does not show anything. Your code works right for the example, but not with my function. Any idea?

Comment: The integral doesn't seem to be defined around *x* =0? The following works : *x* =[-10,-9.975,-9.950,...,-0.05] (399 steps) : `\multido{\nX=-10+0.025}{399}{...}` and using -1e6 for -\infty `\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{integral}{t | y[0]}{-1000000}{\nX}{2}{0.0}{Euler^(-1/(t*(2-t)))}`

Comment: @AlexG I try to compile your PSTricks code but I get error as the following: https://i.imgur.com/9rnt4YE.png . My pst-ode ver. is 0.12

Comment: @chishi  I'll have a look at it asap.

Comment: @TrongVuong : Thank you for reporting. Indeed, this is a bug, introduced in v0.11, file `pst-ode.pro`, which occurs when stepping in negative direction (d *t* <0). Fixed in v0.14 which is on the way to CTAN. Or: https://gitlab.com/agrahn/pst-ode .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/QAGS-adaptive-integration-with-singularities.html) (GSL) via the FFI of LuaJITTeX (and LuaTeX ≥ 1.0.3).  Needs `--shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
typedef double (*gsl_callback) (double x, void * params);

typedef struct {
  gsl_callback F;
  void * params;
} gsl_function;

typedef void gsl_integration_workspace;

gsl_integration_workspace * gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (size_t n);

void gsl_integration_workspace_free (gsl_integration_workspace * w);

int gsl_integration_qags(gsl_function * f, double a, double b, double epsabs, double epsrel, size_t limit,
                         gsl_integration_workspace * workspace, double * result, double * abserr);
]]

local gsl = ffi.load("gsl")

function gsl_qags(f, a, b, epsabs, epsrel, limit)
   local limit = limit or 50
   local epsabs = epsabs or 1e-8
   local epsrel = epsabs or 1e-8

   local gsl_function = ffi.new("gsl_function")
   gsl_function.F = ffi.cast("gsl_callback", function(x, params) return f(x) end)
   gsl_function.params = nil

   local result = ffi.new('double[1]')
   local abserr = ffi.new('double[1]')

   local workspace = gsl.gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(limit)
   gsl.gsl_integration_qags(gsl_function, a, b, epsabs, epsrel, limit, workspace, result, abserr)
   gsl.gsl_integration_workspace_free(workspace)

   gsl_function.F:free()

   return result[0]
end

function f(x)
    tex.sprint(gsl_qags(function(t) return 4/math.sqrt(1+t^4) end, x, 2*x))
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={f(\x) = \directlua{f(\x)};}
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    use fpu=false, % very important!
    no marks, samples=101,
    ]
    \addplot {f(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]