# Can I graph display maths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, pgfplots, pstricks

I'd like to graph these expressions

1. [image]

   ```
   \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}dx+\sum_{n=1}^2\left[\left(\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}\cos(nx)dx\right)\cos(nx)+\left(\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}\sin(nx)dx\right)\sin(nx)\right]
   ```
2. [image]

   ```
   \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}dx+\sum_{n=1}^5\left[\left(\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}\cos(nx)dx\right)\cos(nx)+\left(\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}\sin(nx)dx\right)\sin(nx)\right]
   ```
3. [image]

   ```
   \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}dx+\sum_{n=1}^{10}\left[\left(\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}\cos(nx)dx\right)\cos(nx)+\left(\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x)}\sin(nx)dx\right)\sin(nx)\right]
   ```

Is it possible to graph them without having to tediously convert them all into pgfplots-maths by hand?

Comment: [A related topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129741/how-to-plot-a-function-in-integral-form-with-tikz) that might help.

Comment: What do you want to graph there?  These expression just evaluate to some number.  To graph something you need a parameter.

Comment: @HenriMenke x is the variable. I realise I made a mistake though, the x in the cosnx and sinnx parts is the variable to graph against, the x inside of the integrals should be a separate varaible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot a function in integral form with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129741/how-to-plot-a-function-in-integral-form-with-tikz)