# Plot complete Fermi-Dirac integral in Lualatex

Tags: luatex, plot, asymptote, integral

I am trying to plot this function with lualatex

[image]

Comment: Did you run `lualatex` with the `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX)  or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) switch?

Comment: Are you sure you want to plot an indefinite integral?

Comment: @AlexG: OK. Thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> This answer has been published as an article in
>
> - H. Menke, “Tutorial: Using external C libraries
>     with the LuaTeX FFI”, TUGboat, **39** (1), 37–40 (2018)
>
> The PDF is available here: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121menke-ffi.pdf

You can use the [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/QAGI-adaptive-integration-on-infinite-intervals.html) (GSL) via the FFI (Foreign Function Interface) of LuaJITTeX (and LuaTeX ≥ 1.0.3).  The FFI needs the `--shell-escape` option.

The function you are plotting is a [complete Fermi-Dirac integral](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Complete-Fermi_002dDirac-Integrals.html) for which the GSL has functions as well.  You are only missing the prefactor with the Gamma function (which I compensate using yet another GSL function).  I plot this on top.  As you can see the curves match perfectly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
typedef double (*gsl_callback) (double x, void * params);

typedef struct {
  gsl_callback F;
  void * params;
} gsl_function;

typedef void gsl_integration_workspace;

gsl_integration_workspace * gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (size_t n);

void gsl_integration_workspace_free (gsl_integration_workspace * w);

int gsl_integration_qagiu(gsl_function * f, double a, double epsabs, double epsrel, size_t limit,
                          gsl_integration_workspace * workspace, double * result, double * abserr);

double gsl_sf_gamma(double x);
double gsl_sf_fermi_dirac_half(double x);
]]

local gsl = ffi.load("gsl")

local gsl_function = ffi.new("gsl_function")
local result = ffi.new('double[1]')
local abserr = ffi.new('double[1]')

function gsl_qagiu(f, a, epsabs, epsrel, limit)
   local limit = limit or 50
   local epsabs = epsabs or 1e-8
   local epsrel = epsrel or 1e-8

   gsl_function.F = ffi.cast("gsl_callback", f)
   gsl_function.params = nil

   local workspace = gsl.gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(limit)
   gsl.gsl_integration_qagiu(gsl_function, a, epsabs, epsrel, limit, workspace, result, abserr)
   gsl.gsl_integration_workspace_free(workspace)

   gsl_function.F:free()

   return result[0]
end

function F_one_half(eta)
    tex.sprint(gsl_qagiu(function(x) return math.sqrt(x)/(math.exp(x-eta) + 1) end, 0))
end

function F_one_half_builtin(eta)
    tex.sprint(gsl.gsl_sf_gamma(1.5)*gsl.gsl_sf_fermi_dirac_half(eta))
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={F_one_half(\eta) = \directlua{F_one_half(\eta)};},
  declare function={F_one_half_builtin(\eta) = \directlua{F_one_half_builtin(\eta)};}
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    use fpu=false, % very important!
    no marks, samples=101,
    xlabel={$\eta$},
    ylabel={$F_{1/2}(\eta)$},
    ]
    \addplot {F_one_half(x)};
    \addplot {F_one_half_builtin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never thought such things are possible with latex (LuaTeX)!

Comment: If needed, I can elaborate on what is going on in the code.  Just ping me.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Your answer inspired me to try and understand how the ffi interface works. Here is my attempt to [interface with Julia](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/interfacing-with-julia/)

Comment: @Aditya Amazing!  I have also submitted this answer with more details to TUGboat.

Comment: @Aditya Very nice blog article!  If you want to parse C headers rather than repeating definitions, have a look at https://github.com/umegaya/ffiex (seems to be pure Lua)

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thanks for the link to ffiex. I'll try it out. Nice that you are writing a more detailed answer to TUGboat. Would you mind sharing the draft with me? Thanks.

Comment: @Aditya I sent it to the email address you use on the ConTeXt mailing list.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thanks! BTW, here is another approach for including `.h.` files: http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/LuaJIT-FFI-purely-using-h-files-and-handling-the-multiple-definition-attempts-td6068068.html. The linked code basically just reads the `.h` file and uses it as an argument for `ffi.cdef`.

Comment: @Aditya I see.  But that will not work with the majority of header file out there, as `ffi.cdef` does not support any C preprocessor statements.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I see. [Reading more closely](https://github.com/ayourtch/luajit-fun/blob/master/ffmpeg/ffmpegtest.lua#L17), I see that it runs `gcc -E` on the file (which asks gcc to stop after running the preprocessor stage). Running that on `julia.h` gives a 44k LOC. Not sure if `ffi.cdef` will handle that. But it does make it easier to copy paste the function signatures that are needed.

Comment: This stuff is amazing. Kudos to Henri and Aditya for coming up with really clever stuff like this.

Comment: @HenriMenke With my up-to-date TeXLive 2019, it does not work anymore. I get `[\directlua]:24: could not load library gsl stack traceback: [C]: in function 'ffi.load' [\directlua]:24: in main chunk. \luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }`. Do you know if something changed? Note: I do have `gsl` on my system but I thought it came with luatex anyway. Am I correct?

Comment: @cjorssen No, it doesn't come with LuaTeX.  You say `gsl` is installed but the error message says that `gsl` can't be found.  Try `ffi.load("/full/path/to/gsl/dynamic/libray")`.

Comment: If this code does not work, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624474/8425).

Answer (score 7):

This function from the 
[GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/QAGI-adaptive-integration-on-infinite-intervals.html).
can be also accessed by means of
the internal Asymptote module `gsl`.

Unfortunately, it is not mentioned in the main Asymptote docs
among the other available GSL functions,
but its name (`FermiDiracHalf()`) can be deduced from the source files.

```
// plotFermiDiracHalf.asy
// 
//   run 
//
// asy plotFermiDiracHalf.asy
//
//   to get a stangalone plotFermiDiracHalf.pdf 

settings.tex="lualatex";
import graph; import math; import gsl;
size(9cm);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(8pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"+"\usepackage{amsmath}"
+"\usepackage{amsfonts}"+"\usepackage{amssymb}");

real sc=0.5;
add(shift(-11*sc,-2*sc)*scale(sc)*grid(22,19,paleblue+0.2bp));

xaxis("$\eta$",-5.2,5.2,
  RightTicks(Step=1,step=0.5),above=true);
yaxis("$F_{1\!/2}(\eta)$",0,8.2,
  LeftTicks (Step=1,step=0.5,OmitTick(0)),above=true);
pair f(real eta){return (eta, FermiDiracHalf(eta));}
draw(graph(f,-5,4.7),darkblue+0.7bp);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

PSTricks is very good at numerical integration.
Here we make use of package **`pst-ode`** to numerically solve this integral function by the RKF45 method.

The same method is used for plotting the [error function, erf(*x*)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481740), which is also an integral function. Yet another integral function example:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145174 .

First, we re-formulate the function integral as an initial value problem:

[image]

Then, we solve the initial value problem by means of `\pstODEsolve` several times with different *η*-values to get the solution curve. Note that the precision does not depend on the number of plot points. 201 *η*-values are sufficient to get a visually smooth curve:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-ode,pst-plot}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Fermi-Dirac integral
% #1: eta
% #2: PS variable for result list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\F(#1)#2{%     two output points are enough---v   v---y[0](0) (initial value)
  \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{retVal}{y[0]}{0}{80}{2}{0.0}{sqrt(t)/(Euler^(t-#1)+1)}
  %             integration interval t_0---^   ^---"\infty"
  % `retVal' contains [y(eta,0) y(eta,\infty)], i.e. the solution at t=0 and t=\infty.
  %
  %  initialise empty solution list given as arg #2, if necessary
  \pstVerb{/#2 where {pop}{/#2 {} def} ifelse}
  %  From `retVal', we throw away y(eta,0), and append eta and y(eta,\infty) to our solution
  %  list (arg #2):
  \pstVerb{/#2 [#2 #1 retVal exch pop] cvx def}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%solve function integral, 201 plotpoints: -5,-4.95,...,4.95,5
\multido{\nEta=-5.00+0.05}{201}{
  \F(\nEta){diracInt} %result appended to solution list `diracInt'
}

%plot result
\begin{pspicture}(-1.3,-1)(0.2,5)
  \psset{xAxisLabel={$\eta$},yAxisLabel={$F_{1/2}(\eta)$},xAxisLabelPos={c,-1.8},yAxisLabelPos={-1.6,c}}
  \begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,Oy=-1,Ox=-6,Dx=2,Dy=1](-6,-1)(-6,-1)(6,8.5){8cm}{5cm}
  \listplot[linecolor=red]{diracInt}
  \end{psgraph}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! A good answer.

Answer (score 3):

One can plot the [series expansion around zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20a%5E(0.5)%2F(e%5E(a-x)%2B1)da%20from%200%20to%20infinity):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-.1,0) -- (2.2,0) node[right] {$\eta$};
  \draw[-] (-.05,.7) -- (+.05,.7) node[left] {\tiny$0.7$\text{ }};
  \draw[->] (0,-.1) -- (0,2.2) node[above] {$F_{\frac12}(\eta)$};
  \draw[-] (0,-.05) -- (0,+.05) node[below] {\tiny$0$};
  \draw[scale=1,domain=0:1.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{
    -0.5*pi^(0.5)*(
    0.5*(2^(0.5)-2)*(2.61238)
    +(2^(0.5)-1)*(-1.46035)*\x
    -0.5*(1-2^(1.5))*(-0.207886)*\x^2
    -(1/6)*(1-2^(2.5))*(-0.0254852)*\x^3
    -(1/24)*(1-2^(3.5))*(0.00851693)*\x^4
    )
    });
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]