How to plot a function in integral with ln function with TikZ?
how to plot the function
$f:x\mapsto
\int_0^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2*ln^2(t)}}\, \textrm{d}t$

with TikZ?
tnx

Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

I not have understood the question. Add a minimal tex code editing your question.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129741/47927 maybe ...

What do you want?

The question is poorly descriptive!

thanx
it work in the web site
but on my document
it's not working

Wasn't almost the same question posted recentöy?

@MS-SPO, There is an older, yet similar question.

@AlexG, it was probably this one, reviiewing the OPs date of post and BlackMild's almost instantaneous answer. My bad ...

Does this answer your question? How to plot a function in integral form with TikZ?

@smail065 if you work on a computer, you have to install Asymptote in order to compile

As in the link suggested above, Asymptote is a suitable drawing tool in this case. I just mimick @g.kov 's code.


// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import graph;
size(300,200,IgnoreAspect);

real f(real t){return (t==0)?1:1/sqrt(1+t^2*(log(t))^2);}
real F(real x){return simpson(f,0,x);}
//real a=20;
real a=1000;
draw(graph(F,0,a,n=200),red+1.5pt);

string noZero(real x) {return (x==0)?"":string(x);}
xaxis(LeftTicks(noZero,Step=a/5));
yaxis(RightTicks(noZero,Step=1));

string s="$F(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{x}\frac{\textrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^2\ln^2(t)}}$";
label(s,point(E),SW);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));

You can put the asy code inside a LaTeX document.
Explanation and comments The integrand is not defined at zero, so to tell Asymptote know how to calculate the integral, one may write (also see this link)

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Note that $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} t\ln(t)=0$. One may write   
\[f(t)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2\ln^2(t)}},\quad &t\not=0\\
\qquad 1,\quad &t=0.
\end{cases}
\]

\[F(x)=
\displaystyle\int_0^{x} f(t)\;\textrm{d}t, \quad x\geq 0.\]

We see that $F(0)=0$, $F'(x)=f(x)\geq 0$, and $\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty} f(t)=1$.

Therefore $F$ is increasing to infinity \[\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} F(x)=+\infty.\]
\end{document}


thank you bro
but i search for latex code to draw the curvr of the function
because i wrote the correction for an exam

put the asy code inside \begin{asy} ... \end{asy}, you will get a latex code https://www.overleaf.com/read/fcghypyvqpgn#90464b

if you want a TikZ code, then try (hard) as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129741/how-to-plot-a-function-in-integral-form-with-tikz TikZ is not strong enough for this task

Plotting with PGFplots, definite integral evaluation using package pst-ode (RKF45 method). Since the integrand is not defined at t=0, we start integration at t=1e-9.

Typeset with lualatex or latex + dvips + ps2pdf -DNOSAFER, at least two times:
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pst-ode}

\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll,saveData]{integral}{t | y[0]}{10^-9}{20}{201}{0}{1/sqrt(1+(t*ln(t))^2)}

\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{integral.dat}{}{dummy text\end{document}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$F(x)$,
      xmin=0,xmax=20,ymin=0
    ]
    \addplot[red,thick] table {integral.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


tnx you so very much
