# Runaway argument using int() function in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

The MWE below yields

```
Runaway argument?
3\pgfflt@EOI \ifpgfmathfloatparsenumberpendingperiod \pgfmathfloat@a@Mtok \ETC.
./TeX-SE.tex:29: Paragraph ended before \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

when I attempt to use the `int()` function as documented in the `pgf` manual:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `floor` plot is added just to show that the syntax is correct. So, commuting out the second `\addplot` produces an output.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle
]
%% This works
\addplot [
    jump mark mid,
    domain=-3:3,
    samples=100,
    very thick, red
] {floor(x)};
%%% This now no work.
\addplot [
    jump mark mid,
    domain=-3:3,
    samples=100,
    very thick, red
] {int(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seemingly, it is an implementation problem of `int` .

Comment: If this is related, then you [can't do it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103569/4778) (and if you can, not easily).

Comment: @Alenanno `int` is the “integral part”, the question you refer to is about drawing the graph of an antiderivative.

Comment: @egreg I see, I thought it was related. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this bug I am posting my workaround, until the bug is fixed. I defined

```
MyInt(\x)=x-mod(\x,1)
```

which yields:

[image]

### Notes

- `MyInt()` produces results identical to the current *broken* `floor()` function.  Corrected version is defined as `Floor()` in the MWE as per
  [How to Graph Floor/Ceiling Functions in LaTeX (PGFPlots)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118406/how-to-graph-floor-ceiling-functions-in-latex-pgfplots).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{
    declare function={Floor(\x)=round(\x-0.5);},% floor() is broken.
    declare function={MyInt(\x)=x-mod(\x,1);},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3.2, xmax=3.2,
    ymin=-2.2, ymax=2.2,
    axis lines=middle
]

\addplot [
    jump mark mid,
    domain=-3:3,
    samples=100,
    very thick, red
] {MyInt(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```