# Plotting the graph of a integral function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I would like to know how I can plot the graph of the following function in Latex or Tikz.

```
$f(t)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{t}\alpha(s)ds}{\int_{-2}^{-1}\alpha(s)ds}$,
```

where

```
$\alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
```

is defined by,

```
 e^{\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)}} in [-2,-1]
```

and zero outside of this interval.

Comment: This is a integral function, I guess that there exist a diference to plot graph of this functions.

Comment: What have you tried? No doubt there are some differences, but why can't you adapt the example linked, consulting the documentation to figure out the adjustments you need? Right now, this is just a do-it-for-me and reads like a do-my-homework-for-me, too.

Comment: Then here are your alternative duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103569/can-pgf-plot-the-integral-of-any-specified-function https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129741/how-to-plot-a-function-in-integral-form-with-tikz

Comment: If you have a specific problem when you come to plot this particular function, please ask a question explaining the particular issue and including the code you've got.